# Proper way to pass vectorized input to element_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector

I often find myself wanting to align the x-axis labels on my plots differently based on their location, with values on the left left-aligned and values on the right, right-aligned. However, `element_text` doesn't have [official support for vectorized input](https://community.rstudio.com/t/avoiding-warning-vectorized-input-to-element-text-is-not-officially-supported/73413) (and [never will](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3492)?) so I'm wondering how to solve this in proper `ggplot2` fashion.

The problem: overlapping x-axis labels (and truncated on the far right)

```r
library(ggplot2)
v <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2, facet=gl(2, 2))
gp <- ggplot(v) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = c("Minimum", "Maximum")) +
  facet_wrap(~facet)
gp
```

[image]

My solution:

```r
gp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=c(0, 1)))
```

[image]

Except:

```
Warning message:
Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
ℹ Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.
```

**What's the correct way to differently-align text in a ggplot if vectorized `element_text` isn't supported?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Claus Wilke states [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3492#issuecomment-524593601) that his ggtext package **does** support the use of vectors in this way and it will continue supporting it in the future. As thomasp85 (Thomas Lin Pedersen) says in the thread "FWIW, I think most of the use cases for this hack can be solved properly using element_markdown()", i.e.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

v <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2, facet=gl(2, 2))
gp <- ggplot(v) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = c("Minimum", "Maximum")) +
  facet_wrap(~facet)
gp
```

[image]

```r
gp +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown(hjust = c(0, 1)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hmmm I was hoping for something that didn't require loading an additional library. I'm curious about the `ggplot2` crew's vision for how this should go. Is it just a bad idea in general because the labels are offset from the ticks? It seems like it's just a technical problem, so is it worth opening a feature request on the GitHub even though they already seem aware this is an edge case?

Comment: Great point; I don't think it's a bad idea, it's just not a 'standard' use-case. Based on the discussion thread on github the ggtext code is designed to support vectorised inputs and the ggplot2 code isn't (and they plan to deprecate this 'hack' for `element_text()` in the future) so it might be worth posting a feature request and see what they say.

Comment: After doing some more searching, it looks like the concerns I have were already raised and considered not worth implementing - [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4533) says basically the same things I would and the "official" response seems to be that this isn't going to happen and we'll just have to keep fingers crossed that `ggtext` sticks around. Thanks for your help though!